# In PHP, is it good practice to sanitize/escape a string to use it in an exception message?

Tags: php, exception, sanitization

I am wondering, are exception messages usually considered safe for output? Or is it ok if an exception message contains an unsafe string? (for XSS, etc)
What kind of sanitization would be suitable?

E.g.

```
function lookupOrExplode(array $array, $key) {
  if (!array_key_exists($str, $array)) {
    // @todo Sanitize $key before using it in the exception message?
    throw new \InvalidArgumentException("Key '$key' not found.");
  }
}
```

I personally would think that in a catch() block, the message from an exception has to be regarded as potentially unsafe, because it could come from anywhere. But the throw() statement can still attempt to make the message *somewhat sane*.

But maybe someone can provide more detailed recommendations, e.g. based on standards for common php frameworks...

Note: Let's not debate whether InvalidArgumentException is the correct or suitable exception class to use in this case. This is a quick and dirty example, the focus should be on the string handling.

Comment: I would consider whenever a output has user input in it, it needs to be escaped

Comment: As was said, unless you are outputting user created content (something a user typed into a field and submitted to your application) there is no need to escape the content.

Comment: Unless your application is only for internal use, I would strongly recommend against outputting them 'as-is'...

Comment: Yes.. but should the variable $key be sanitized before inserting it into the exception message?

Comment: And what kind of escaping.. because at this point we don't know where the exception message will be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

There are no strict rules regarding how exceptions are used, only the rule that you shouldn't expose internal workings.

The exception `InvalidArgumentException` is not semantically or securely viable for being read by the user regardless of what the message contains.

In the example below, a custom exception `HTTPException` is going to mean, "to be output to the client".  The message will contain information relevant to the application, browser, and user.

Your classes and function, that deal with the interface (UI and browser for example), would be expected to throw HTTP exceptions for user error, or regular exceptions for fatal error.

```
/**
 * Class HTTPException
 *
 * new HTTPException($message, $code)
 * new Exception($message, $code)
 *
 * Arguments are compatible:
 * $message, error message
 * $code, http error code
 */
class HTTPException extends Exception
{

}

// Further up the stack

try {
    // ...
} catch (HTTPException $exception) {
    // Catch HTTP exception
    // Respond directly to user with message
    // or create error screen from template
} catch (Exception $exception) {
    // Catch any exception.
    // Return 500 error or any other error.
}
```

Another thing I'll point out is that `InvalidArgumentException` is more suited to invalid arguments, i.e. invalidly formatted, invalid types etc.

PHP lacks built-in exceptions for the nitty gritty, but you can create them yourself.  A good source for building your standard exceptions is .NET

https://mikevallotton.wordpress.com/2009/07/08/net-exceptions-all-of-them/

For your function I would use, `KeyNotFoundException`, because it describes exactly what the problem is, and so long as the value is the correct type and format, it is not invalid.

So you new code might look like:

```
class NotFoundHttpException extends HttpException
{
    public function __construct($message, Exception $previous = null)
    {
        parent::__construct($message, 404, $previous);
    }
}

try {
    $v = lookupOrExplode(/* args */);
} catch (KeyNotFoundException $exception) {
    throw new NotFoundHttpException(
        sprintf('Key "%s" not found in lookup table.',
            $exception->getKey()));
}
```

Comment: You are right about custom exception classes. But this would rather belong in a separate Q/A. Here I am only interested in how to deal with strings. I am going to update the question to clarify this.
Otherwise this looks like a useful answer.

Comment: @donquixote Ah, well, the relevancy to strings was superseded by my thought process whereby a user's own data can be fed back to them without escaping. That is unless it needs to be HTML escaped, but that is not "this function's" responsibility given the name.

Comment: Ok. I think the worst things that could happen is (a) that the string inserted in the message is very long, or (b) that it contains the quote character which makes it look as if the string would end there. Both of these are survivable.

Comment: If you update the post to point this out at the beginning, I will mark it as accepted. There might still be other interesting answers saying things like "In framework X, there is a policy that exception messages should be trimmed to 300 characters"..

Comment: @donquixote I can't really do that because its not what I would do.  For me, an exception like this wouldn't have been reached if the key was too long, because it would have failed a length validation check first.